# Can't append blade syntax with JQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I have create a form with Laravel blade syntax below:

```
<div class="form-group" id="addstudent">
        {!! Form::label('student_name', 'Student Name :') !!}
        {!! Form::select('student_name', $students, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'name' => 'student_id[]']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::button('Add More Student', ['class' => 'btn btn-info', 'id' => 'btnaddstudent']) !!}
    </div>
```

and with JQuery code below:

```
<script>

      $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#btnaddstudent").click(function(){
          $("div#addstudent").append("<div class='form-group'>{!! Form::label('student_name', 'Student Name :') !!}{!! Form::select('student_name', $students, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'name' => 'student_id[]']) !!}</div>");
        });
      });

    </script>
```

I tried to append the addstudent id so everytime the users click on my button the form will append the blade syntax below:

```
<div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('student_name', 'Student Name :') !!}
        {!! Form::select('student_name', $students, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'name' => 'student_id[]']) !!}
    </div>
```

and it didn't work for me. Is there anyway for this to work out? Thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, its a quote type problem.

Try that:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btnaddstudent").click(function(){
          $("div#addstudent").append('<div class="form-group">{!! Form::label("student_name", "Student Name :") !!}{!! Form::select("student_name", $students, null, ["class" => "form-control", "name" => "student_id[]"]) !!}</div>');
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Laravel uses double quotes for generated Blade attributes.